# How does object destruction work in this case?

Tags: c++

```
class Name_value
{ 
public:
    int value;
    string name;

    Name_value(string a, int b) 
        : name(a), value(b)
    {
    }
    ~Name_value()
    {
        cout << "Object destroyed" << '\n';
    }
};
vector<Name_value> v;
int main()
{
    int score;
    string name;
    
    cout << "Enter a name and value." << '\n';
    while (cin >> name >> score)
    {
        Name_value thedata(name, score);
        v.push_back(thedata);
    }
    for (Name_value x : v)
    {
        cout << x.name << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a name and value.
c 18
Object destroyed
d 15
Object destroyed
Object destroyed
a 14
Object destroyed
Object destroyed
Object destroyed
b 21
Object destroyed
Object destroyed
Object destroyed
Object destroyed
```

So my question is what exactly is happening here? Say I type c 18 I create an object put it into the vector and then that object gets destroyed, then I type d 15 which again creates a new object puts it into the vector and destroys it. Why am I getting more destroyed objects everytime?

Comment: you should read about move and copy constructor

Comment: @George The old objects are deleted anyway even when moved. It's the content within that is moved if allowed to do so. If  members are trivial in nature, nothing is really saved from a copy anyway. In this case the OP could squeeze a *little* out of this because the string member `name` could be moved. But regardless, even after a move those source objects are still destroyed; they're just (hopefully) shells of their former selves in the process.

Comment: Note that if you `reserve` enough storage for vector element and then `emplace_back(name, score)` into `v`, you should observe no destructor call (until the vector itself gets destructed).

Comment: @George Note that one destruction comes from the `thedata` variable in each iteration. Vectors typically double their capacity.

Comment: Please note that you can avoid most of the unneded copies: https://godbolt.org/z/WK1eon6f1

Comment: I have augmented your MCVE a bit to show more of what's happening: [demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64e6b57086fff6fa)

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? It is a valid, more or less well formed beginner's question. It's not a stupid question at all.

Comment: @S.M. you could just edit the title. Shouldn't we be nice to new contributors?

Comment: @Jabberwocky yeah my original title was something like "Stupid question about object destruction" so I just edited it myself but feels like a little much to downvote my question just because I had "stupid question" in the title..